# How to set the estimate argument correctly for roc_auc() function in yardstick package

Tags: r, roc, auc, yardstick

I want to compute the AUC for a model.

```
library(yardstick)
data(two_class_example)
```

This code works.

```
roc_auc(
  two_class_example,
  truth = truth,
  Class1,
  options = list(smooth = TRUE)
)
```

I like to specify arguments so that my code is easier to read and debug.

```
roc_auc(
  two_class_example,
  truth = truth,
  estimate=Class1,
  options = list(smooth = TRUE)
)
```

This gives the following error

> Error in metric_summarizer(metric_nm = "roc_auc", metric_fn = roc_auc_vec,  : formal argument "estimate" matched by multiple actual arguments

Please explain this error. I thought the Class1 column is the vector of estimated class probabilities.

Comment: According to the help page for the function, the `Class1` variable falls in the `...` argument, not the `estimate` argument (in fact, no such argument appears to exist). About the `...`, it reads: " 
A set of unquoted column names or one or more dplyr selector functions to choose which variables contain the class probabilities. If truth is binary, only 1 column should be selected. Otherwise, there should be as many columns as factor levels of truth." Basically, there's no argument for you to worry about specifying.

Comment: @phil I'd upvote your comment if it was posted as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the help page for the function, the Class1 variable falls in the `...` argument, not the estimate argument (in fact, no such argument appears to exist). About the `...`, it reads:

> A set of unquoted column names or one or more dplyr selector functions to choose which variables contain the class probabilities. If truth is binary, only 1 column should be selected. Otherwise, there should be as many columns as factor levels of truth.

Basically, there's no argument for you to worry about specifying.